# A Simple Password Puzzle. Or Maybe Not

Tags: logical-deduction, password

### Prologue:

> It's me, KryptonOmega, back with a password puzzle. Enjoy!

### Puzzle:

[image]

### Edits:

1. Add "unique" in condition 2 for clarification.
2. Length of answer is five. (Why would you expect more when there are five underscores only???)

Comment: Welcome back! :D

Comment: oh hiii @jafe :)

Comment: are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \varepsilon$ each a single digit?

Comment: @MarkMurray an intriguing question, I haven't thought of that lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> S E V E N

Because

> Using a letter's sequence number value:
>  1. (s + v + n) = (11 * e) **or** (19 + 14 + 22) = (11 * 5) = 55 
>  2. **v** is the largest valued letter among the 5 letters
>  3. n + e = s **or** 14 + 5 = 19
>  4. e >= e 
>  5. (e + e) < n **or** (5 + 5) < 14
>  6. **e** is the duplicate
>  7. seven is a prime number

Explanation

> Well, the way I figured out this answer was noticing the 5 spaces for the answer and the fact that the answer was prime, but wouldn't be so easy as to actually be the word "PRIME". 
>  So, my next thought was "SEVEN" because condition 6 said their were duplicates in the variables.
>  I then saw condition 2 was fulfilled with "v" and condition 3 worked out mathematically and wished I was better at writing up this type of answer because this took forever.
> So, I ran the math for the remaining conditions and it actually was a valid answer. So, I decided to answer.

Comment: No logical deduction seen. Please explain how you reached the answer through deduction. Keep it up!

Comment: Explain my thought process as to how I figured out the clues?

Comment: ok, this answer is correct. this isnt logical deduction tho. ill add my answer as explanation, and accept this later :) well done

Comment: @Omega, I appreciate that. I'm sure doing so will help me to understand the proper way of explaining this type of question's answer in the future.

Answer (score 8):

### Setting the scene

We have five numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon$ satisfying seven conditions. These numbers must all be non-negative integers (we assume). I tried assuming they are all single digits (at most $9$), but got a contradiction as shown in [the first revision of this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/100479/1), so we know $\gamma\geq10$.

### Step-by-step deduction

- Firstly, can any of them be zero?

  > $\alpha\neq0$ since it's the first digit, so $\beta\neq0$ by condition 1. Also $\gamma\neq0$ by condition 2, and $\epsilon\neq0$ by condition 5. The only one which *might* be zero is $\delta$, since all we know about it is inequalities.
- The password is prime, so

  > $\epsilon$ must be, or end in, one of $1,3,7,9$.
- Substituting condition 3 into condition 1, we find

  > $\gamma+2\epsilon=10\beta$, so $\gamma$ is even and $\beta\geq2$, meaning $\epsilon\geq3$.
- Going back to condition 6, we notice

  > $\gamma$ is not the same as any of the others (by condition 2), neither is $\alpha$ (it's bigger than all the others, by condition 3, nonzeroness, and condition 4), neither is $\epsilon$ (again bigger than all the others, by condition 5). So we have $\beta=\delta<\epsilon<\alpha<\gamma$.
- Now conditions 4 and 6 are used up, and condition 5 gives

  > $\epsilon>2\beta$, therefore $\epsilon\geq7$ by the prime condition and $\beta\geq2$. Using $\gamma+2\epsilon=10\beta$, that means $\beta\geq3$.

Note that after fixing $\beta$ and $\epsilon$, the others are completely determined:

> $\delta=\beta,\alpha=\beta+\epsilon,\gamma=10\beta-2\epsilon$. So we need $10\beta-2\epsilon>\beta+\epsilon$, which means $\epsilon<3\beta$. Overall, $2\beta<\epsilon<3\beta$, and also $\epsilon$ is a prime ending.

Let's now just try possibilities starting from the smallest:

- If $\beta=3$, then we must have

  > $\beta=\delta=3$, $\epsilon=7$, $\alpha=10$, $\gamma=16$, giving the password $1031637$, but that's a multiple of 3.
- If $\beta=4$, then we must have

  > $\beta=\delta=4$, $\epsilon=9\text{ or }11$, $\alpha=13\text{ or }15$, $\gamma=22\text{ or }18$, giving the password $1342249$ or $15418411$, but these are not prime.
- If $\beta=5$, then we must have

  > $\beta=\delta=5$, $\epsilon=11\text{ or }13$, $\alpha=16\text{ or }18$, $\gamma=28\text{ or }24$, giving the password $16528511$ or $18524513$, of which the latter is not prime but the former is.

### Final solution for the password

> $16528511$.

Comment: Condition 2 is not met, since alpha is now = gamma. Sorry, and keep it up!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton You didn't say it's the *unique* largest!

Comment: ok i'll add that. yes it is the unique largest. - done, edited.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton OK, got it now.

Comment: length is 5. ^^^

Answer (score 1):

### OP's Answer

The answer is, [as shown by @MacGvyer88](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100478/a-simple-password-puzzle-or-maybe-not/100500#100500),

> SEVEN

but they did not provide logical deduction, so here it is.

@RandAlThor has proven that a five-digit number is impossible as the answer. Yet it is mentioned in the clarifications that the length is 5. Therefore it may be a

> Word of length five.

Well, intrinsically, you can say that

> we only need to consider "THREE" "SEVEN"

but I will try to deduct this on the approach that we only know that it is a five-letter word and that A1Z26 is used.

From (1) the max of LHS is 26+25+25 = 76 since gamma is unique largest. In other words beta <= floor(76/11) = 6.

Therefore beta is

> A B C D E or F.

And in second position it is very likely a

> vowel. so A or E are most likely.

Notice condition 6 regarding duplicates.

From (2) gamma isn't a duplicate.

From (3) we know that alpha ≠ epsilon.

Based on all this we know that either beta or delta is one of the duplicates.

(5) shows that beta ≠ epsilon and delta ≠ epsilon, so epsilon is out.

We now have alpha, beta and delta being possible duplicates.

(3) shows that alpha ≠ beta

Therefore either alpha = delta or beta = delta.

Given beta = A or E most likely, we now have

> `+a_+_ or +e_+_ or _a_a_ or _e_e_`

And this should be enough, given (7) for you to make out

> SEVEN.

---

**I am challenged to prove why beta is A or E. First of all I said "most likely". Secondly, here it is if you need proof.**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I struggle with these types of explanations as my thought process is often not explained easily. I was going to write, thanks to @Rand's explanation, we know it can't be a number sequence. So, I kind of get it. However, I am not a practiced logician. So, this is actually a lot for me to grasp.

Comment: Please use logical deduction to explain why "beta = A or E" :P

Comment: @Cireo done. see edit :)

Comment: @MacGyver88 youre welcome, hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Alpha = 16, Beta = 5, Gamma = 28, Delta = 5, Epsilon = 11

Checking

> 1) 16+28+11 = 11*5
>  2) 28 is unique largest
>  3) 11+5=16
>  4) 5 >= 5
>  5) 5+5 < 11
>  6) Beta and Delta are both 5
>  7) 16528511 is prime

Partial explanation (to be continued):

> Under the assumption that the Greek letters denote single digits, we quickly see that there is no solution. By trial and error, we show that Beta = 2, 3 and 4 won't work, and Beta = 5 yields the answer given above. Perhaps the larger value for Beta can give different solution, so this is not unique...

Comment: The "trial and error" process you mention is quite lengthy unless you figure out a lot more restrictions on the possible choices, isn't it? (I guess you did and that's the "to be continued" part :-) )

Comment: please use logical deduction. also, length of answer is five. (Why would you expect more when there are five underscores only???)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Well, you did not specify that each underscore represents a *digit*, so they've assumed it's *numbers* instead

Comment: @Chronocidal well they are not digits coz i googled and it says digits are strictly numbers only